# Laravel Eloquent saving relational model fails

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have Laravel Eloquent class `Collage`

```
class Collage extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the User that owns this Collage.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Collage migration schema

```
Schema::create('collages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and `User`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Get all Collages that belongs to this User.
     */
    public function collages()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Collage');
    }
}
```

but when I do this on tinker

```
$user = App\User::find(1)->first();
$collage = new App\Collage;
$collage->name = 'Collage';
$collage->user = $user;

//and save
$collage->save();
```

throws me error `QueryException`

```
General error: 1 table collages has no column named user
```

Comment: Seem you want to add new user to collage?

Comment: no i just wanted to ad user id (who owns this collage) to collage.

Comment: I think, from what I see you need to change the relationships(I am assuming your columns): `$this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');` and `return $this->hasMany('App\Collage','id','user_id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change**

```
$collage->user = $user
```

**To**

```
$collage->user_id = $user->id
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your schema to make the relationship,

```
Schema::create('collages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('name')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

That way Laravel Eloquent will automatically make references to the relationship.

Comment: Yes i have added this line but still the same, Im using sqlite, may be sqlite cause this?